# "No application can perform this action" when trying to view a text message image

Tags: sms, photos, images

I’m using an LG Tribute phone (Virgin Mobile) with Android.  I’ve noticed recently when someone sends me a text message with an image in it, and I click the image, I get a warning that reads

```
Note
No application can perform this action.  Enable disabled built-in application?
No / Yes
```

When I click the “Yes” button, nothing happens.  Previously, I could click on the image and it would open up in some kind of application (I forget which) where I could enlarge the image.  What is the built-in application the message is referring to?  How do I view a larger version of the image that is in a text message?

Comment: I've been having the same issue with my phone running 5.0.2. Wonder if it's something that I accidentally disabled?

Comment: Go to Settings app -> Apps -> All apps -> Disabled and give us the screenshot of the list you see there.

Comment: There is no "All Apps" tab, only an "All" tab but when I click on it, I just see a list of applications, I don't see a "Disabled" tab or any item taht reads "Disabled."

Comment: @Dave check at the buttom of that tab whether there are some apps marked as "disabled" (often, disabled apps are moved to the end of the list). If not, scroll through the entire list (sometimes, disabled apps are kept just between others). The term "Disabled" is usually printed to the right-side of disabled entries.

Comment: Hi, At the bottom of "All" are the applications that fall in lowest alphabetical order -- "WhatsApp," "Xt9 Dictionary," and "YouTube."  When I scroll through all the apps in that tab, I don't see "Disabled" to the right of any of them.  What specific application is the error message referring to?  I can look for that.

Answer (score 1):

The application needed to do this is Google Photos.  Installing that solved the problem.

Comment: This somehow implies that there is no image viewer app installed or they are disabled, including the stock Gallery app..? I can't recall anymore what the Android Settings menu looks like on Android 4.4, but usually, system/stock apps are not shown by default and the user needs to enable it from the overflow menu. Perhaps, just perhaps, this was missed when checking back then...